# Using different materials on overlapping UV textures

Tags: materials, uv, shader-nodes

everyone!
I have a simple model of a parfum box which in reality has a golden reflective finish on some parts. I cant seem to achieve the same result in Blender. I applied the Texture on the box and then created a separate UV map for the golden finish but I'm unable to combine them effectively. I've tried using a mix RGB node but this doesn't give me enough control over the part that needs to be golden so I tried with Mix Shader node but I'm unable to change properties without affecting the texture underneath. I would really appreciate some help because I feel stuck...

Node setup
[image: Node setup]

This is the result in Eevee
[image: This is the result in Eevee]

And the result in Cycles due to not being able to affect only upper textures
[image: And the result in Cycles due to not being able to affect only upper textures]

Comment: Create a b&w image that you'll use as a mask, plug it into the factor of a Mix Shader that mixes a golden material (a Principled BSDF with yellow base color, Metallic at 1 and Roughness at 0) and the image that is supposed to be underneath. If it still doesn't work please pack your images and share your file